# Forge Viewer: Adding authentication token to local file access

Tags: autodesk-forge

when using the forge viewer to view locally stored files, How can I add an authorization token to the header of all file access requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately load options won't cut it when set to local environment so you will head to make do with:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function(){
    Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
        Authorization: '233',
        ...//Other custom headers
    }
```

[image]

Comment: this doesnt seem to work when loading texture .jpg files